# I am getting an error trying to get cron to run on/against a docker container. Anything I am missing?

Tags: linux, docker, cron

I followed [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-internet-speed-monitor/) guide on my unRAID server within my docker container (siwatinc/ubuntu-playground) and got it to work successfully.
I installed cron on a docker image called UbuntuPlayground and all the stuff from the guide worked successfully until the cron task failed. I looked up the problem and I think it's because the docker image doesn't have systemd (IDK what that actually is) isn't running so cron needs special stuff downloaded to get it to work. So I moved on from that. But if I am in the bash of my docker container with this command:

```
docker exec -it UbuntuPlayground bash
```

I can run ./speedtest.sh from the home directory where the shell script is located and it will do the speedtest on the internet and upload to Google Drive. So I found that also, if I leave the docker image and from the SSH on the unraid server I run this command:

```
docker exec -it UbuntuPlayground /root/speedtest.sh
```

it will run the code successfully. I can even see the speedtest results on my google drive.
So i tried making a cronjob on unraid to jsut run that command. So I tested cron with:

```
0 * * * * docker exec -it UbuntuPlayground /root/speedtest.sh
```

I let it run for a few hours and checked it and it wasn't working. So I tried making a shell script on the host to run the command. Here is the connents:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -it UbuntuPlayground /root/speedtest.sh
```

Thats just called speedtest.sh. So I added speedtest.sh to my crontab:

```
0 * * * * /root/speedtest.sh
```

Then I went to sleep and I got this problem in my /var/log/syslog

```
Nov  3 21:00:01 TrevNas2 sudo:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/docker exec -it UbuntuPlayground /root/speedtest.sh
Nov  3 21:00:01 TrevNas2 crond[1861]: exit status 1 from user root /root/speedtest.sh
Nov  3 21:00:06 TrevNas2 sSMTP[26673]: Creating SSL connection to host
Nov  3 21:00:06 TrevNas2 sSMTP[26673]: SSL connection using TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Nov  3 21:00:07 TrevNas2 sSMTP[26673]: Authorization failed (534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor j79sm5194000ywj.11 - gsmtp)
Nov  3 21:00:07 TrevNas2 crond[1861]: exit status 1 from user root /usr/local/sbin/mover &> /dev/null
Nov  3 22:00:01 TrevNas2 sudo:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/docker exec -it UbuntuPlayground /root/speedtest.sh
Nov  3 22:00:01 TrevNas2 crond[1861]: exit status 1 from user root /root/speedtest.sh
Nov  3 22:00:06 TrevNas2 sSMTP[21643]: Creating SSL connection to host
Nov  3 22:00:06 TrevNas2 sSMTP[21643]: SSL connection using TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Nov  3 22:00:07 TrevNas2 sSMTP[21643]: Authorization failed (534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor x64sm4861319ywb.55 - gsmtp)
Nov  3 22:00:12 TrevNas2 crond[1861]: exit status 1 from user root /usr/local/sbin/mover &> /dev/null
```

So, it is failing with exit code one. I don't understand what the problem with this is. I figured it is some problem that is just over my head. I googled exit code one and can't find anything. Should I try to fix the issue in the docker container in running cron or fix the issues in cron on my host machine? Or does anyone know how to fix either?

If you've read all of this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it is not working in the docker container. cron was not running within. Using [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429076/crontab-in-docker-container) stack exchange I found that I need to run the following command:

`/etc/init.d/cron start`

After that I tested a basic crontask that would touch a file every minute which worked and then I added

```
*/30 * * * * /root/speedtest.sh
```

to my crontab again and I can see the lastest speedtest ran. So It was just a case of cron not actually running.